# useState is undefined after set

Tags: arrays, reactjs, async-await, use-state

hey i'm trying to extract the object i got from the function "fetchMovies()"
and i did that with .then and map() and tried to set the array state setMovies.

so the problem i'm facing is that, this line - console.log(transformedMovies) can show the log but,
this line - console.log(Movies) shows an empty array.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { fetchMovies } from '../lib/api';


async function FetchedMovies() {
    const [Movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const result = await fetchMovies()

    result.then((data) => {
        const transformedMovies = data.map(movieData => {
            return {
                key: movieData.id,
                id: movieData.id,
                Duration: movieData.Duration,
                Image: movieData.Image,
                Rate: movieData.Rate,
                Title: movieData.Title,
                Year: movieData.Year,
                Categories: {
                    cat_id: movieData.Categories
                }
            }
        })
        console.log(transformedMovies)
        setMovies(transformedMovies);
    })
    console.log(Movies)
    return Movies;
}

export default FetchedMovies
```

this is the function that im using

```
export async function fetchMovies() {
    const response = await fetch(`${firebaseApi}/Movies.json`);
    const data = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(data.message || "Error");
    }

    const fetchedMovies = []

    for (const key in data) {
        const moviesObj = {
            id: key,
            ...data[key]
        }

        fetchedMovies.push(moviesObj);
    }
    return fetchedMovies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, `result` is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and it has not had the data yet. You need to use `await` to wait for the actual data from that promise

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { fetchMovies } from '../lib/api';


async function FetchedMovies() {
    const [Movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
       const result = await fetchMovies()
       const data = await result //wait for the actual data

       const transformedMovies = data.map(movieData => {
            return {
                key: movieData.id,
                id: movieData.id,
                Duration: movieData.Duration,
                Image: movieData.Image,
                Rate: movieData.Rate,
                Title: movieData.Title,
                Year: movieData.Year,
                Categories: {
                    cat_id: movieData.Categories
                }
            }
        })
        console.log(transformedMovies)
        setMovies(transformedMovies);
    }, [])

    console.log(Movies)
    return Movies;
}

export default FetchedMovies
```

Comment: it helped to log the data but now the console.log(transformedMovies) is executed 3 times, in my api i have an object with 3 values maybe thats the problem ?

Comment: @EmanualWondemenh I added `useEffect` to avoid executing that API call multiple times, you can check it out again

Comment: One thing I just noted down that, `Movies` data will be empty but after fetched, it will be filled with API response @EmanualWondemenh

Comment: i added useEffect and async to the useEffect but it prints an empty array.

Comment: `Movies` is data or a component? @EmanualWondemenh

Comment: its supposed to be the useState value after i did setMovies(transformedMovies)

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't format movies data directly in `fetchMovies`. React's components are asynchronous, we cannot get data immediately in states @EmanualWondemenh